# Sign in Sam's office

Tags: cheers

In Sam's office in the TV show *Cheers* there is a yellow sign that reads "Electric work by Memphis..." but I can't make out the whole thing.  What does it say?  The sign can be partially seen in this screen-grab from Episode 3 - "The Bartender's Tale"

[image: Still showing yellow sign]

Comment: Got a screenshot?  A little searching shows the Sun studios in Memphis had a [predominantly yellow, round sign](http://www.elvispresleypedia.com/video/lokaties/foto/6b.jpg), but I doubt that's it because the text you quoted is nowhere on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a Memphis Electric Co. sign.

[image]

Comment: My goodness...so simple it eluded me