# Who are depicted in a photo in Sam's office?

Tags: cheers

Inside Sam's office there is a black and white photo by the door.  Looks to be two boxers holding a baby.  Who are they?

[image: Two boxers with baby]
[image: Boxers holding baby]

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Do you have a picture of his office that shows the photo in question? That would help us a lot in trying to figure out what it might be.

Comment: Seems to be related to: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24401/sign-in-sams-office

Comment: brighter version is here : https://jasonchinftw.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/mw-aj253_cheers_20110315145456_mg.jpg

Answer (score 7):

It appears to be a photo of two boxers : Max Baer and Primo Carnera, probably around when they had a match in 1934.

Why Sam would have it in his office is anyone's guess.

Edit to add: Although a clue might be that perhaps the child is [Max Baer jr](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0046319/) .... who later became a comedic actor on The Beverly HillBillies !

[image]

Comment: Sam was a former Baseball pitcher.  It wouldn't be unusual for him to have sports memorabilia in his office.  Nice find, BTW.

Comment: The kid looks like Spanky from the Little Rascals.